# Django. Error saving empty string to DateTimeField(blank=True)

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with a DateTimeField (blank=True, null=True). However, when I try to save an empty string in it, I get the following error:

```
>>> from courses.models import Event
>>> x = Event.objects.last()
>>> x.date_start = ""
>>> x.save()

django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
```

I have never seen this, any ideas? All my migrations are up to date.

Comment: `blank=True` is something that has effect on the *modelforms* of that model. Not the model itself. `blank` does not mean it accepts an empty string. It only means that if you leave the element blank, that it will use the default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`blank=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank) has impact on *modelforms*, not on the model itself. It does not mean that the element accepts an empty string. `blank=True` simply means that the field is not required. In case the value is not specified, it will use the default value.

But at the model layer, nothing changes. Since your field has [**`null=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null), the default in case you do not fill in the value will be `None`, so you can use:

```
>>> from courses.models import Event
>>> x = Event.objects.last()
>>> x.date_start = None
>>> x.save()
```